# What does wx mean in the word wxWidgets?

Tags: wxwidgets

wxWidgets, wxWindows, wx.NET... I am just curious about what do these letters "wx" mean. Could you help me, please? Is it an abbreviation or what?

I tried to google it, but it did not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [history page on the wxWidgets web site](https://www.wxwidgets.org/about/history/):

> wxWidgets (w for Windows, x for X) started off with support for XView
>   and MFC 1.0